# Android download video (mp4) using download manager

Tags: android, video, mp4, android-download-manager

I would like to download mp4 video from URL and store into SDCard along with display downloading progress to user. I have tried with different ways but not able to download mp4 file successfully. I also find some demos and ideas via search but not specifically mp4.

If anyone has any idea then please share.

Comment: Why are you not able to download an MP4 file? There is nothing specific about MP4 files in general that make them download differently. What problems do you have with it? Are you unable to download it from a desktop machine as well, or is it just an Android device?

Comment: Show a small code example of how you download a file. Can you download a text file to SD card? Then you change it from text file to MP4 file path. Show a link to the MP4 (if possible). Could be a protected file.

Comment: FALSE, this is not simple task like text file download. You can download mp4 like text file but after download the mp4 not play correctly in android.